# { w | at every odd position of w is a 1}

Tags: computation-theory

The task is to construct a DFA for this language over the alphabet {0,1}.

I have constructed a DFA that consists of 4 states and that does not accept an empty word. However, in the answers they give a 3 state DFA that accepts it.

Why should my DFA accept an empty word if in the empty word there is no 1 at the odd position which means that it is not in the language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused why should an empty string be a part of a mentioned set.

Let's take a look at another example. Consider you have a set of all possible strings having every character equal to 0. Such strings would be 0, 00, 000, 00000, etc. What about an empty string *? It actually pertain to this set as well. Empty string does not violate the definition of the set.

Compare this example with yours. You should check every odd position of the string and if you'll find anything other than 1 you should say that it is not an element of you set. It is not said anything about whether a string should have an odd position to be checked.

Comment: In your example, does the empty string not violate the definition because there are no characters in it so it basically satisfies the condition "having every character equal to  0"?  I am still not sure when I should accept an empty word. Can I assume that my finite automata should accept an empty string if there are no restrictions on the length of strings?

Comment: @Caroline, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 5):

The only requirement is that any symbol at an odd position must be `1`. There is no requirement for a particular number of symbols, and specifically not that there be at least one.

Therefore, a DFA with an initial state where `0` leads to a rejection state and where `1` leads to a second state which accepts either symbol and returns to the start would be an acceptable answer, and would accept the empty string. This would be a three-state machine:

[image: Diagram of suggested DFA]